# Bst- Why did my Bst worked after chaning node* to node*&?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I implemented BST and my implementation looks like this

```
 void insert(node*&r,int key){      // 1 ) node* r 2) node*&r
    if(r==NULL){
        r=new node(key);
        return;
    }
    c++;
    if(r->key > key){
        insert(r->right,key);
    }
    else if(r->key <key){
        insert(r->left,key);
    }
  }

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    node *root=NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        insert(root,x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was clear before why **node*&** not  **node***.But I have mental blockage today.I am confused that if we use **node*&** than we will edit the root permanently that is the identity of BST hence we will loose BST.On the other hand I am confused why it doesn't work on using **node*** .can anyone please explain this in detail.Which one and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now because you pass the pointer by reference, hence the function in which it's passed can modify it. Otherwise you pass the pointer by value, and at the exit from the function, the pointer passed as argument is not modified.

Look what's happening here:

```
node *root=NULL; // so initially root is nullptr
```

then, in the `for` loop, you have

```
insert(root,x); // better take it by reference, otherwise root is not modified
```

At the exit from insert, `root` is modified **only if** is passed by reference, otherwise, if passed by value, it stays `NULL`. Just remember that a pointer behaves like any other variable, and in C++ it is passed by value by default.

Comment: I have query that suppose initially root was (0x7fffffff(let) ) and when we insert value in bst let 8.The root will change permanently because of line r=new node(key) line since we are passing root by reference.So when we have loost our root how would we be able to insert starting from top for second and third insertions..Since it is modified.Like we used temporary pointer similary in case of linked list insertion preserving root..I am sorry if I was stupid.

Comment: @thoughtfulme No no, you modify `root->right` (in the line `insert(r->right,key);`) and similarly `root->left`, not `root` itself. You only modify `root` if it's initially `NULL` (the first `if` test), which is OK since that's the first time you insert in the tree. Try to mentally "run" the algorithm for 3-4 values, and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong..Since we are doing this using recursion.The permanent changes will occur for root->left and root->right since they are now our root when called recursively.So our "actual root " will change only in the first case when we have our bst empty and as soon as we have some value on the bst like 2,5.. we will traverse to the down on either side(depending on keys) and when we will find the place to correctly insert.We will change "permanently" either left child or right child of that node....not actual root since it is recursion.Sorry for such a long comment :(

Comment: @thoughtfulme Yes, exactly, and that's why it works.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot **hugs**. Now I can sleep better :) .Please tell me one more thing(little offtopic but necessary for me) I knew this what you taught me but some day I suddently gets blank and have serious mental blockage.Any advice what to do in this case when someone have mental blockage like this.Thanks a lot btw :)

Comment: @thoughtfulme First take a break :), then use a simple simple example, together with a debugger in which you can watch the value of the variables.

Comment: Is this completely normal ?

Comment: All of us have troubles in understanding some issues at some times, so yes it's normal.